# Google Admob on a Null Object Reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

I am trying to integrate Google Admob into my project, but in running into an issue.    I will go over my project first.

My project is structure on 2 main Java files and around 7 .xml files.   The .xml files are shapes, the .xml files are neither linear or relative layout.  In my main Java file I draw those .xml file shapes to the screen.  So I do not depend on a .xml layout for my project.

EXAMPLE OF SHAPE .XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemes.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

<solid android:color="#000" />
<corners
android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
android:topLeftRaidus="17dp"
android:topRightRadius="17dp" />
</shape>
```

So I am trying to add Google ads into my project, so I will need to add the Google ad .xml code.  But I'm not for sure where.   When I put my ad .xml code in one of the shapes .xml code I get and error that says "You can not put this here".

So I thought a little bit and realized I still have my .xml layout file that was created when I created my project.  So I add my ad .xml code there and had no error.   So next I added my Java code in my mainactivity.java,  into the oncreate, and I had no error.

I have 2 Java files, one is my mainactivity.java and the other one is my MV.java.  My MV.java is where I draw all my .xml shapes to the screen.

My Java code looks like this:

```
protect void onCreate(bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
view = new MV(this);

Adview adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);

}
```

I do not get any error with my Java code.  So I thought I could run my application and have my ad.  But when I run my app I get this error.

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.Adview.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.Adrequest)' on a null object reference
```

I also did add the Google ad code in my build.gradle and androidmanifest.xml.

how can I get ads to work?

Comment: Where you have setup setContentView in above code ?

Comment: In my oncreate, in MainActivity.java

Comment: Please post your full MainActivity.java code.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the NullPointerException because `adView` is null.

You need to declare the AdView in your XML.
It should be declared in the layout that is loaded by your Fragment/Activity.